# how to include numbers inside and outside a tikz element in Latex?

Tags: latex, tikz

How can I number the circles from inside and outside, for example I need the green circles to be numbered 1,2,3 from the inside and user1,user2,user3 from the outside.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\layersep{3 cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]


    % Draw the input layer nodes
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4} 
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
        \path[yshift=0.5cm]
            node[input neuron] (I-\name) at (0,-\y cm) {};

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,6}
        \path[yshift=0.5cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,6}
            \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {SCs};
    \node[annot,left of=hl] {Users};
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
% Draw the input layer nodes
% This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4} 
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
    \path[yshift=0.5cm]
        node[input neuron,label={160:user\y}] (I-\name) at (0,-\y cm) {\y};
...
```

Above, 160 is an angle at which the outer label is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `{}` to `{\y}` in line 26 of your MWE:

```
node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {\y};
```

and adding

```
\foreach \y in {1,...,3}
    \node[yshift=0.5cm] at (-1,-\y cm) {user \y};
```

between lines 21 and 23, you get an output which is also coherent with the answer by @xxa:

[image: screenshot]